# PayPal IPN Configuration

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been trying to configure IPN for a website I'm trying to build. Long story short, I want this to be the control over my database entries, and other API's to place orders elsewhere.

I just cannot get it to work. Checking the IPN history on the PayPal site looks like it's sending ok to the URL (which I've specified in the button, NOT via Paypal), but absolutely nothing happens. From my script, I'd expect an email stating either Failure or Success. I also tried setting a session variable in my listener.php which I check on the return url (although I think this isn't set due to the IPN and return pages not necessarily running in succession)...

Anyway, would someone be able to cast their eyes over what I have and let me know where I've gone wrong, as I've been pulling my hair out over this!

```
<?php
// listener.php
$_SESSION['listener'] = 'reached';


// read the post from PayPal
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "Conection: Close";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
   // HTTP ERROR
}
else {
   fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

   $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);
   if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

      $to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'IPN VERIFIED';
      $message = $req;
      $headers = 'From:noreply@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
   }

   else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

      $to      = 'mymail@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'IPN INVALID';
      $message = $req;
      $headers = 'From:noreply@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   }

   fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Please let me know if I should supply further details.

### UPDATE

I've checked the value of `$res` by emailing it to myself, and although I was expecting either "VERIFIED" or "INVALID", I in fact had this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 09:14:48 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=3B4lq1GFXyCeV6nNKFDjhiS0CC1T77tsq9IXk6bQiM3OI8T1hI6ih0f7I0FDZQH3e6lqT0RXEH4DqKZUJ9uKzNyIxPANl_6326ntzQsqsVA_2KO7z0wvIKf_T_9BwLagSrsP7r7X5TO3G15FCnUK-PIqOlv16zGTZrmLood4Ezql7U17t2emfzW_CfbgFDDZogUFvIUhjCqzN1pLiejHhgKADJj0jNpmjOeMXdY9XWtytXo9NWUH0OuAlrsoYaU3beBi2MK86WLaZnSNBxbrpVOG9W70_lS8fxJ5QPA1K-jXhBAf3p4eqKXzoKOeEqNOCeKEnemyqxrhkQx8lUBnTWo_BdBfMinfEhqfyisMv13mwLixHKKJ9Kkd3jRQGFwW0139gBT4Hw_hUvbJ2AfLVxKeFrfb64x10B3C8Y8rb8bJ6nrwUm7-DJS-3He; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 08-Aug-2024 09:14:49 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 10-Aug-2016 09:14:49 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1407748488825362; path=/; expires=Wed, 03-Aug-44 09:14:
```

Many thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 0):

This has now been solved using cURL - surprsingly simple to implement! https://gist.github.com/CodeAngry/5957044